# Nuxt vuetify not recognised in Nuxt.config.ts

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxt3, vuetifyjs3

new error for me, trying to install Nuxt vuetify

Install with

```
npm install --save-dev @invictus.codes/nuxt-vuetify
npm install
```

Then I add the module to Nuxt.config.ts

```
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@invictus.codes/nuxt-vuetify'
  ],
}
```

That all works fine but then when I try and add the settings vuetify is not recognised

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@invictus.codes/nuxt-vuetify'
  ],
  vuetify: {

  }
})
```

I get the error

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'vuetify' does
> not exist in type 'InputConfig<NuxtConfig, ConfigLayerMeta>'

.
Never come across this before, can anyone tell what is causing this ...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is no longer maintained
Please refer to the official installation instructions provided by Vuetify using Nuxt or an alternative Nuxt Module.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#using-nuxt-3